# Сократить/упростить условия с проверкой на пустые значения

Tags: python, условия, рефакторинг

При чтении файла "test.json" иногда встречаются пустые значения, к примеру:

```
{
    "fruit": {
        "1": {
            "title": "",
            "color": "синий",
            "smell": "",
            "form": "квадрат"
        },
        "2": {
            "title": "груша",
            "color": "",
            "smell": "бутилацетат",
            "form": ""
        },
        "3": {
            "title": "",
            "color": "оранжевый",
            "smell": "этилбутират",
            "form": ""
        },
        "4": {
            "title": "арбуз",
            "color": "",
            "smell": "",
            "form": "круг"
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно чтобы программа написала "пусто", если где-то значение отсутствует. Для этого было написано несколько условий:

```
import json

input = "груша" # Здесь была функция поиска, её я заменил на переменную, это то что поступает в программу.

with open('test.json', 'r', encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    file = json.load(f)
    for key in file["fruit"]:
        title = file["fruit"][key]["title"]
        color = file["fruit"][key]["color"]
        smell = file["fruit"][key]["smell"]
        form = file["fruit"][key]["form"]
        if input == title:
            id = key
        elif input == color:
            id = key
        elif input == smell:
            id = key
        elif input == form:
            id = key

    title = file["fruit"][id]["title"]
    if title != "":
        title_print = title
    else:
        title_print = "пусто"

    color = file["fruit"][id]["color"]
    if color != "":
        color_print = color
    else:
        color_print = "пусто"

    smell = file["fruit"][id]["smell"]
    if smell != "":
        smell_print = smell
    else:
        smell_print = "пусто"

    form = file["fruit"][id]["form"]
    if form != "":
        form_print = form
    else:
        form_print = "пусто"

    print(f"номер: {id}")
    print(f"название: {title_print}")
    print(f"цвет: {color_print}")
    print(f"запах: {smell_print}")
    print(f"форма: {form_print}")
```

Здесь представлен короткий пример программы, в оригинале огромное множество (минимум 20шт) подобных условий:

```
    form = file["fruit"][id]["form"]
    if form != "":
        form_print = form
    else:
        form_print = "пусто"
```

Нужно сделать рефакторинг кода, сократив все условия (if-else) с проверкой на пустые значения до минимума. Если такое вообще возможно.

Comment: Тот кто Вам сказал, что при именовании переменных можно использовать зарезервированные слова и названия функций стандартной библиотеки, Вас жестко нае… обманул в общем. Что касается решения, то более чем уверен, что если бы Вы полностью описали задачу (в целом, ту которую должна решать Ваша программа) то более чем уверен, Вам бы предложили гораздо более эффективный способ ее решения нежели тот, который угадывается по тому коду что Вы предоставили.

Comment: Ну например убрать всю конструкцию ``if input == title:
            id = key
        elif input == color:
            id = key
        elif input == smell:
            id = key
        elif input == form:
            id = key``. Зачем тут все эти if elif, если выполняется одно и то же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вместо `if` использовать `or`:

```
form = file["fruit"][id]["form"]
form_print = form or "пусто"
```

Ну и в одну строку:

```
form_print = file["fruit"][id]["form"] or "пусто"
```